# ASP.NET MVC Jquery Server function not functioning

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to load a table and put it in a page after it has loaded so the JQuery Code in the html page is :-

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '@(Request.RawUrl + "/getcomment")',
        dataType: "html",
        data: '',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (response) {
            $("#tblComments").html(response);
        },
        error: function (response) {
        }
    });

});
```

and in the controller, I have

```
        [HttpPost]
    public string getcomment()
    {

        return "<table><tr><td>Name</td><td>MiscellaneousUser</td></tr></table>"; 
    }
```

However when the page is run, instead of the table being loaded into the div tblCOmments, the whole page is loaded into the division.  The routes command i'm using is :-

```
routes.MapRoute("OneRule", "page/{id}/{misc}", new { Controller = "document", action = "Index", misc = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

How can I get the getcomment to fire, it doesn't fire when I debug, the View is executed but the controller isn't.

Comment: Is this the only route you have?

Comment: What error are you getting in the browser console

Comment: try using the browser tools to see where the information is getting posted.. or download fiddler.. you should be using `public ActionResult getcomment()` and `return Content("");`

Comment: odds are that you're just hitting your Index action again because your route is wrong... not sure why you'd need a route for this

Comment: {id} looks suspicious. It got no default value and it's definitely not an action method.  As per the code, "getcomment" is an action method. So in your route you should have a provision for that.

Comment: Sanish, the answer is no, I have multiple routes for different controllers and also multiple routes to document.  e.g. /page/one, /leaf/one are both processed by document controller.

Answer (score 0):

As per this route you have added, this is going to hit, "document" controller and "index" method always. Route is missing the Action method provision which makes "index" as the action method to hit.

**Update:**

I tried exact the same routes and code you gave and was able to reproduce the issue. There are multiple problems. Firstly, the route is wrong. Like I mentioned earlier action method is not part of your current route and getcomment() will never get called until you modify your rote to this,

```
 routes.MapRoute("OneRule", "page/{id}/{misc}/{action}", new { Controller = "document", action = "Index", misc = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

So when you post through Ajax, you have a route in place which handles the URL.

Comment: adding {action} made the page to be not found

Comment: What is the URL you have now in your browser before post?

Comment: What is the controller name in which you have getcomment() action method?

Comment: document has the getcomment() function

When I look at fidder, the webpages accessed are 

http://localhost/page/article1
http://localhost/page/article1/getcomment
http://localhost/page/article1/getcomment/getcomment

Comment: I am kind of reproduced your scenario. And I was able to get it working. Let me update everything I did in the answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127357/discussion-between-sanish-joseph-and-miscellaneoususer).